# Handling repeated events in a log

Tags: events, logging, spam, system

I have a logging system where some events are repeated infinitely. for example:

12:03 - Restart attempted
12:03 - Restart failed
12:02 - Restart attempted
12:02 - Restart failed
12:01 - Restart attempted
12:01 - Restart failed

This might go on for days. I imagine there are standard ways that systems deal with spammy events like this.

What are the common ways logging systems deal with these kind of events without flooding the log system?

Comment: Is this a text file or Windows's Event log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to coalesce matching entries that repeat within some time delta of each other, something like

```
12:03 - Restart attempted [3 times since 12:01]
12:03 - Restart failed    [3 times since 12:01]
12:02 - Something
11:23 - Restart attempted [17 times since 11:21]
```

Answer (score 0):

They typically either compel you to fix the problem, or have flags to suppress them. And I think properly so.

Error logs are typically chronically underadministered and undermonitored anyway. If it's an application I'm in any way involved with, I'd as soon see as much flag-waving as possible if it gets someone's attention.